# Check if cell is equal to a cell in a string

Tags: google-sheets

I want to check if A2 is strictly equal to a cell from O4 to O12 and then display the corresponding cell. For example : A2 is equal to O6, so I display P6

This is what I tried :

=IF(A2 = O4:O12; P4:P12; "40%")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2 = O4:O12, P4:P12, "40%"))`

There's a good tip how to fast convert usual formula into `ArrayFormula`:

1. set cursor insidet the formula
2. hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Edit1.** For your regional settings use semicolon:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2 = O4:O12; P4:P12; "40%"))`

your link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K4wdLboozyAXmG_601BkdP_1UoK_aETMGBmnmQ-S9Zo/edit#gid=0

**Edit2.**
For matching any value from the range try:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A9:A14;D9:E14;2;0);"40%"))`

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AkelBmZUOkdAawpbfaeGxCsr3NSgkNqX9kgf_qdWm9M/edit#gid=0

Comment: Thank you for you reply but it's not working "#ERROR". I am using google spreedcheat

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ozegLArdyHP3V8K1cV6-F1jK0a0G_53Phy1prySsT8s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It is working but something weird is appening. It's parsing data in the cells bellow my function. I just want to check and display the data in the cell A2.

Comment: It is not weird, it is natural behaviour of a function: it compares A2 with any value in O4:O12, and when equals gives P4:P12, else 40%

Comment: Ok I see. So is there a way to only display the "TRUE" value ?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ozegLArdyHP3V8K1cV6-F1jK0a0G_53Phy1prySsT8s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Made an edit. Please edit your question in order to make clear for others what you meant to do, because comments are not the best place to see the question details.